# ways to store last N messages to the database where old messages will be automatically deleted

Tags: mysql, database, chat, pusher

I have a chatroom application made with pusher. I would want to store let's say the last 10 messages on the database (MySQL). So, there would be frequent writes. But, only 10 will be stored and any old messages will be deleted.

Example:

1. Message 1 to 10 will be stored on the database
2. Message 11 comes in, that's the time Message 1 will be deleted

These last 10 messages will only be retrieved when a user visits and logs in to the chatroom the first time, so that he/she will be able to back read the most recent messages on the chatroom

Is there a common 'practice' how to do this or a better way perhaps?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best performing MySQL solution for this would be the following...

First, create your table as an InnoDB table to prevent table locks when writing.

```
CREATE TABLE chat_messages (
    id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    ....
    message VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

Optionally, before querying, you may want to set your transaction isolation level to "read uncommitted", which will not wait for locks to be released before executing.

```
SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ UNCOMMITTED;
```

Then, just query the last 10 records by ordering by id DESC and LIMIT 10.  This will be exceptionally fast, as it's using the clustered index (primary key) to sort.

```
SELECT * 
FROM chat_messages
ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 10
```

Finally, you could run a clean-up process on a cron nightly to delete chat messages when activity is low.

```
0 0 * * * mysql -hlocalhost -uusername -ppassword -e "DELETE FROM chat_messages WHERE id < (SELECT MAX(id) - 10 FROM chat_messages)"
```

Comment: What do you suggest for faster inserts, I wouldn't use the inserted data on real-time by the way. This is just a database for the recent chat messages which gets loaded on first visit. Should I use ``INSERT DELAYED``

Comment: The inserts should be exceptionally fast as-is.  You're inserting very simple data, and only doing insert / select during peak hours, so there will be no table-locking issues getting in your way.

Answer (score 1):

I would think about using really mysql for this, I think a ram-database is a better choice. At least use a memory-engine.

You could create a after-insert-trigger which counts the entries and deletes the oldest too many entries. Or you create a cronjob which deletes the oldest "too many" entries.

See also: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10017798/2277620

Anyway the select should read only the last 10 entries with `limit 10` as in the other answer.

Comment: thank you for this idea, I really liked it. however, I really have to accept the other one because of his effort to explain the other piece of the puzzle.

Comment: Yeah, his answer provides more details, so I accept the accept. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

I would be tempted to go with either of the above.

Alternatively you could use a trigger on insert to delete records if there are more than 10.

Or if you are happy with a scheduled clean up job by have no cron job access then you can use scheduled events within MySQL.

Comment: thanks for the idea, I didn't know there is a scheduled event in MySQL :|

Comment: They are not widely known about yet it seems. Down side is it is something extra to think about when backing up and restoring databases.